# javascript - confirm() not working in IE9 but working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have below code in my aspx page, which is working fine in IE8. but not working in IE9.

```
function ProjetFocus() {
        var s = confirm("Do you want to create a new project?");
        if (s == false) {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtProject.ClientID %>').value = "";
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error in console? I don't see anything wrong with above code

Comment: Use `window.confirm` instead of `confirm` and it may work.

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: Confirmation box with yes and no option is not being displayed in ie9. but it is being raised in ie8.

Answer (score 0):

is it in compatipility mode or has javascript disabled for ie9?  [Check this out.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/01f3de19-3996-47ae-85eb-dc4db5b6e1fe/ie9-confirm-dialog?forum=iewebdevelopment)